# How to make radio buttons mandatory for selection in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am working on a small project to create a small window which will ask 3 questions and 2 options as radio buttons will be available for answers. After selecting the answers it will print the users details along with the answers which later i will add into a database. As of now it is working fine with selections, but if no button is selected and clicked on submit button it still picks the 2nd option and allows to enter. Here i want to add a check if no button is selected then a pop up should appear and should ask to select the buttons. I have googled a lot on making radio buttons mandatory but didn't find any appropriate answer. Can some one please help. Below is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import getpass
import socket
from datetime import datetime

root=Tk()
root.title("Survey")
root.geometry("225x225")
root.config(bg="antique white")
root.resizable(width="false", height="false")


day_selected = IntVar()
mood_selected = IntVar()
work_selected = IntVar()

# creating values for entry

staffid = getpass.getuser()
machine = socket.gethostname()
now = datetime.now()
date_str = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
day_sel = day_selected.get()

def done():
    print(staffid)
    print(machine)
    print(date_str)
    print(day_sel)
    print("Good" if day_selected.get()==1 else "BAD")
    print("Good" if mood_selected.get()==3 else "BAD")
    print("Good" if work_selected.get()==5 else "BAD")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Thank you", "Thank you for completing the survey !!!")

lab1 = Label(root, text="  How Was ?", font=("calibri", 20, "bold"), bg="antique white", fg="brown").pack()

lab2 = Label(root, text="Day", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab2.place(x=8, y=50)
r1=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=day_selected, value=1,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=52)
r2=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=day_selected, value=2,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=52)
lab3 = Label(root, text="Mood", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab3.place(x=8, y=100)
r3=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=mood_selected, value=3,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=102)
r4=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=mood_selected, value=4,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=102)
lab4 = Label(root, text="Work", font=("calibri", 14, "bold"),bg="antique white")
lab4.place(x=8, y=150)
r5=Radiobutton(root,text="Good", font=("calibri",12), variable=work_selected, value=5,bg="antique white").place(x=110,y=152)
r6=Radiobutton(root,text="Bad",font=("calibri",12), variable=work_selected, value=6,bg="antique white").place(x=170,y=152)

sub_bt=Button(root, text="Submit",font=("calibri",12, "bold"), command=done, bg="brown", fg="white").pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an if statement to see if it is empty then do what you want, you can change the text on labels to tell the user. then do

```
root.after(1000, lambda: lab2.config(text=somethingsomething))
```

to go back to original text... well radio buttons only have 2 options, on and off, so 2nd option is always selected if the user does not touch it.

Comment: this still doesn't help and it just runs a test and stops the process by its own without running the output. I need to add a pop up when no selection is made and submit it pressed.

Comment: i changed the def set and now it works.                                                                        
 ```                                                                                                                                  
     def done():
    if day_selected.get()<1 or mood_selected.get()<1 or work_selected.get()<1:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("no selection", "Please select the options")
    else:                                                                                                                                        ```

Comment: Very nice, happy to hear that. Please upvote if all is good, so more new unanswered questions get shown in search more, thank you very much :)